# How To avoid stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document when I use a command to change the paage

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver

I have a problem using Ecplise. When I use a command to do something that drives me into another page. For example if I do commands that do not require to change the page it works fine. But when I do one that changes the page, it works, but after that it stops and I get that error. So, there is a portion of the code. After the third command which implies going to another page, the next 2 commands don't work.

```
driver.get("https://mathaus.ro");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();        
        driver.findElement(By.id("Constructii10NavNode")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("changeLocationReference")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.className("close-modal")).click();
```

Comment: When you come back again on the first page. define all the web elements again otherwise they would be staled

Comment: How can I do that? And, also, I do not come back on the first page. I go to the second page, where I have many of the elements from first page, such as "change address" button, which I want to use.

Comment: Constructii10NavNode this you have on left hand side, while changeLocationReference you have on top right corner.  can you tell me what exactly are you trying to do when URL is launched successfully.

Comment: So I just want to go to Constructii10NavNode page, and when I am on that page, to open changeLocationReference and then close it. I want to do a first short test on this website. When I figure this problem, I will add other things too.

Comment: then you should not get any stale element reference. where exactly you are getting it  ?

Comment: After Constructii10NavNode command, the next command is not being executed, and the error appears.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need Explicit waits :

**Code :**

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://mathaus.ro");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("Constructii10NavNode"))).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("changeLocationReference"))).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.close-modal"))).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

**PS :** `Thread.sleep(3000);` is just for visualization purpose. You can remove that. It's not really required